# Find out the total call duration happened between 2 people

Tags: sql

I want to find out the call duration between 2 persons through SQL.
Say "Joe" calling "Mak" and spoke 5 minutes and "Mak" calling "Joe" for 15 minutes then total duration must be 20 minutes.

I tried something with self join but getting duplicates for such calls.

```
SELECT t1.cal1, t2.cal2,sum(t1.dur) as Total 
from tele t1
INNER JOIN   tele t2
ON (t1.cal1 = t2.cal1 AND t1.cal2 = t2.cal2)
GROUP BY T1.CAL1, T2.CAL2;

cal1       cal2    duration (in Mins)
A           B        5
A           B       10
B           A       10
B           A       25
A           D        1
D           C        2
B           C        4
C           B        9
C           B        7
C           A        2
D           C        5
D           B       10
```

Comment: Answer for my code, 
B           A                                                  70
C          A                                                  2
A          B                                                  30
C          B                                                  32
D          B                                                  10
B          C                                                  4
D          C                                                  14
A          D                                                  1

Comment: See [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query) for providing example data and expected results which we need..

Answer (score 3):

The simpler way is to use CASE so you get the unique combinations of col1 and col2 and then group by each combination:

```
SELECT 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal1 else cal2 end col1, 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal2 else cal1 end col2, 
  SUM(duration) duration
FROM tele 
GROUP BY col1, col2
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1123bceff93ca51a821c4135c2f4fc3f).
Results:

```
> col1 | col2 | duration
> :--- | :--- | -------:
> A    | B    |       50
> A    | C    |        2
> A    | D    |        1
> B    | C    |       20
> B    | D    |       10
> C    | D    |        7
```

In case you use SQLServer, you need this:

```
SELECT 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal1 else cal2 end col1, 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal2 else cal1 end col2, 
  SUM(duration) duration
FROM tele 
GROUP BY 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal1 else cal2 end, 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal2 else cal1 end
```

or replace the CASE statements with

Comment: Just a nitpick, is it ANSI-compliant to refer in the `GROUP BY` clause, to columns defined in the `SELECT` clause?

Comment: There needs to be a small correction, Since in above query we get A B 35 & A B 15 also for B C 16 & B C 4
I mean, duplicates as you made changes for B A to A B & C B to B C

Comment: @Vin no you don't. See the demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=1123bceff93ca51a821c4135c2f4fc3f

Comment: @forpas : I am running the same query in SQL. Not sure how but I am getting 8 rows in return.

Comment: Perfect @forpas 
SELECT 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal1 else cal2 end col1, 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal2 else cal1 end col2, 
  SUM(duration) duration
FROM tele 
GROUP BY 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal1 else cal2 end, 
  case when cal1 < cal2 then cal2 else cal1 end

This worked!
Thanks a lot :)

Comment: If this worked you may consider accepting the answer

Answer (score 1):

You will have to dynamically set your columns in a subquery and group the results of it again to achieve your desired outcome:

```
SELECT 
  col1, col2, SUM(duration) 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      IF(cal1 < cal2, cal1, cal2) AS col1, 
      IF(cal1 < cal2, cal2, cal1) AS col2, 
      SUM(duration) AS duration
    FROM 
      tel 
    GROUP BY 
      cal1, 
      cal2
  ) AS m 
GROUP BY 
  col1, 
  col2
```

Comment: Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL. `IF()` is not valid ANSI/ISO SQL standard.  This seams to be MySQL/MariaDB  syntax

Comment: Yes Raymond you are right.
@Miroslav - This code will not work. Please let me know if you find the right code.

Comment: The inner `GROUP BY` and `SUM` seems unnecessary - all the aggregation can be done by the outer query.

Comment: *"The inner GROUP BY and SUM seems unnecessary - all the aggregation can be done by the outer query. "* indeed @Steve a good optimizer would see this also and rewite the SQL without using a subquery..

Answer (score 0):

If a call A to B is equivalent to B to A, then it would probably help if you create a combined column consisting of both parties names - e.g. AB - with the order of the names in the combination determined by the sort order of the strings.

So for example, `CASE WHEN A < B THEN A + B ELSE B + A END AS party_names`.

This will ensure both calls from A to B, and calls from B to A, result in a `party_names` of AB.

You can then GROUP BY and SELECT that column, and SUM(duration).

Comment: Answers to questions tagged with SQL should use ISO/IEC standard SQL. `IIF()` is not valid ANSI/ISO SQL standard..

Comment: Fair point Raymond. A `CASE` statement to the same effect could be substituted instead. Hopefully the OP will get the idea of the approach anyway.

Comment: Well you would have to know that SQL Server (i assume) `IIF(A < B, A + B, B + A)` rewrites internal into  `CASE WHEN A < B THEN A + B ELSE  B + A END` which is ANSI/ISO SQL standard.

Comment: Indeed. I've edited my post to reflect this and correct the error. On reflection and as an aside, I think Miroslav's approach is superior in this case (though I note he has similarly slipped up on ANSI syntax!).

Answer (score 0):

Most databases support `least()` and `greatest()`:

```
select least(t.cal1, t2.cal2), greatest(t.cal1, t2.cal2),
       sum(t1.dur) as Total 
from tele t1 
group by least(t.cal1, t2.cal2), greatest(t.cal1, t2.cal2);
```

For databases that do not, you can use a `case` expression instead.